# Given the PDF, find CDF / E / Var

Tags: probability-distributions

I have the following PDF:

$f_{A} = \frac{\theta}{A^{\theta+1}}$

Assuming that A is defined on the interval $[0, \infty)$, how can I find the CDF (and based on that the Expectation and Variance)?

I did the following:

$F_{A} = \int_{1}^{A} \frac{\theta}{A^{\theta+1}} dy = -A^{-\theta}$

But I am not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two things the integral seems like a typo since you should be integrating over the support up to $y$. Given this the integral will be
$$
\int_1^y \frac{\theta}{x^{\theta +1}}dx  = \left[-y^{-\theta} -(-1)\right] =1 -y^{-\theta} 
$$

you should know your attempt is wrong since by the definition of a probability they are non-negative so the cumulative distribution will be non-negative also.

I am not sure why you need to find the CDF before the expectation but
$$
\mathbb{E}(g(y)) = \int_1^\infty g(y)f_y(y)dy 
$$
so for the first example the mean we have
$$
\mathbb{E}(y) = \int_1^\infty y\frac{\theta}{y^{\theta +1}}dy = \theta \int_1^\infty y^{-\theta} dy = \theta \left[\frac{y^{1-\theta}}{1-\theta}\right]_1^\infty
$$
Since we don't have any information on $\theta$ I will leave it to you to decide if you are correct.